# static library creation

Tags: unix, linker, unix-ar

in general 
we use `ar rcs` command to create a static library on unix.

what does the flag 's' mean over here
 man page says

> Do not generate an archive symbol
>   table.  This can speed up  building 
>   a  large  library in several steps. 
>   The resulting archive can not be used
>   with the linker.  In order to build a
>   symbol table, you must  omit  the S
>   modifier on the last execution of ar,
>   or you must run ranlib on the archive.

i am confused by the sentence
"The resulting archive can
           not be used with the linker.".

do we have to use ranlib for creating the static library after the ar command?
what is the purpose of the ranlib and how is it used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ranlib` utility creates an index in the library that the linker uses to do its lookups. Note that the omit index command in `ar` is uppercase S - the command to build the index is lowercase s, which you should be using. There is no need to use `ranlib` after running `ar rcs`.

Comment: excellent ...now i got to know that i am getting confused with the case of letter "s"